# Geodesics of an ellipsoid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, curves, geodesic

I'm trying to comprehend the solution to the following problem.

> Let $S=\left\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}: x^{2}+2 y^{2}+3 z^{2}=4\right\} \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be an ellipsoid. Show that the intersection $S \cap\left\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}: z=0\right\}$ is a simple closed geodesic in $S$.

Here is the official solution: The intersection $C=S \cap\left\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}: z=0\right\}$ is an ellipse in the plane $\{z=0\}$. The unit normal to $S$ is proportional to $\nabla f$, which is contained in the plane $\{z=0\}$ for all $(x, y, z) \in S \cap\{z=0\} .$ Hence the curvature vector of $C$ is proportional to the unit normal of $S$ along $C$, from which it follows the geodesic curvature of $C$ is zero and $C$ is a geodesic.

The only part that I'm confused about is why the curvature vector of $C$ is proportional to the unit normal of $S$ along $C$. Could anyone help me understand this?

Comment: Both the curvature vector of $C$ and the unit normal of $S$ along $C$ are orthogonal to the tangent to $C$, and lie in the plane $\{z=0\}$.

Comment: @AlejandroEpelde Thanks for the explanation! Can I ask why the curvature vector of $C$ lies in the plane $\{z=0\}$?

Comment: If $\gamma$ is a parametrisation of $C$, then $\gamma(t)\in\{z=0\}$ for all $t$, and hence so is $\ddot{\gamma}(t)\in\{z=0\}$ for all $t$.